# NGINX Rewrite to strip a URL Segment

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have moved my site to a new server running nginx from apache.

The old site structure was:

example.com/NEW/

The new structure:

example.com/

I have a few applications that still reference uploads/files like:

example.com/NEW/assets/images/7871862618261826.jpg

I need to rewrite all the requests that include the /NEW/ parameter.

eg:

example.com/NEW/assets/images/7871862618261826.jpg

should be routed to:

example.com/assets/images/7871862618261826.jpg

My Current Nginx config looks like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.domain.com domain.com;
    return 301  https://www.domain.com$request_uri;
}
```

server {

```
listen  443;
if ($http_host = domain.com) {
    rewrite  (.*)  https://www.domain.com$1;
}

location /NEW/ {

     rewrite ^/NEW(.*)$ $1 last;
     #return 405;
     #return 301  https://www.domain.com$request_uri;
}


server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

access_log /var/log/nginx/domaincom.access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/domaincom.error.log;

root /var/www/domain.com/public_html/;
index index.html index.htm index.php;

 #set default location
 location / {

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;

 }

}
```

How can I achieve the rewrite?

Comment: Your example should do it. What is the question?

Comment: Hi Alexey, It is not rewriting with the block above.

Comment: From the location or rewrite? Or both?

Comment: I have added my complete nginx config. Still not getting the rewrite to work. Anything to do with reverse proxy maybe?

Comment: This config should rewrite as expected. Could you be more accurate in what exactly does not work?

Comment: Thanks Alexey, it was redirecting to root when accessing https://example.com/NEW/assets/images/7871862618261826.jpg.

Answer (score 0):

I Finally got it working with the below location block:

```
location ~ /NEW/.*\.(png|jpg|gif|pdf|doc)$ {

     rewrite ^/NEW(.*)$ $1 last;

}
```

It seems the location block was not being executed as required.